# Exporting sql server table to fixed length text file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a sql server 2008 table with 2-25 fields. I have to read this table and create a fixed length text file consisting of sequential 832 character.

While reading the table the length of different fields are fixed. For example-patient name should start at pos 1 and its length will be 30 chars,next say from position 32 medical record number needs to be displayed whose length is say 13 chars.

Please help me in writing query for that?or any thing can be done through ssis packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast your fields to the char datatype and then use this with bcp queryout

for example, take this query:

```
select convert(char(30), [patient-name])
     , convert(char(13), [medical record nr])
     , convert(char(10), value3)
     , ...
from myTable
```

You can use this in a bcp statement as follows

```
bcp "select convert(char(10), field1), convert(char(10), field2), convert(char(10), value1)  from myDB..myTable" queryout c:\myfile.txt /SmyServer /T /c
```

Note that you need to fully qualify the table name